# GraphQL - Return a nested array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql

I'm making a graphQL query on a json file. See DATA below.
I essentially need to return the entire array as it is into a variable. Imagine simply copying and pasting it in but instead do it using graphQL.

I can make a query like this for example:

```
  const data = useStaticQuery(graphql`
    query {
      allTestJson {
        nodes {
          _106{
            lat
            lng
          }
        }
      }
    }
  `)
```

But this will return null values where some of the arrays don't contain a corresponding object.

```
{
  "data": {
    "allTestJson": {
      "nodes": [
        {
          "id": "f622635c-5c7b-5d18-ba1a-00359821deba",
          "_106": null
        },
        {
          "id": "656e26bb-fd18-5e81-b46a-a2614299d245",
          "_106": {
            "lng": 0.62991339,
            "lat": 51.35365677
          }
        },
        {
          "id": "a50493a2-1ee9-54e9-ada0-992dd739fff0",
          "_106": null
        },
        {
          "id": "001f6b69-7f6c-5bdf-813e-3019f324a0bd",
          "_106": null
        },
        {
          "id": "e9a76677-390a-511b-8fae-4293ffa44569",
          "_106": null
        },
        {
          "id": "f1168a9a-a450-56f0-b75b-9c2a09029a01",
          "_106": null
        },
        {
          "id": "1f431781-8682-57c6-bbe5-09624f1f4f0e",
          "_106": null
        },
        {
          "id": "6ec27c23-27d2-5c1a-b68e-3b2e3edf2163",
          "_106": null
        },
        {
          "id": "016685fb-59dc-5364-a18f-64ccb8358e45",
          "_106": null
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "extensions": {}
}
```

I could split each child array out into their own file and do the below for each file, which does give me back a child array for each which I can just wrap in an array. But this just adds more files and complication that I would rather keep concise to one file.

```
 query {
      allTestJson {
        nodes {
          lng
          lat
        }
      }
   }
```

As I mentioned, essentially I need to return the array below from the query so that I can assign it to a variable something like this: `const coordinates = data.allTestJson.nodes`

Or just this `const coordinates = data.allTestJson`

### DATA

```
[
  [
    { "lng": 0.16627, "lat": 51.39855576 },
    { "lng": 0.160834, "lat": 51.41722107 },
    { "lng": 0.18110999, "lat": 51.43777084 },
    { "lng": 0.21139, "lat": 51.4569397 },
    { "lng": 0.223611, "lat": 51.47333145 },
    { "lng": 0.216666, "lat": 51.47777939 },
    { "lng": 0.218889, "lat": 51.4858284 },
    { "lng": 0.242222, "lat": 51.49888992 },
    { "lng": 0.247777, "lat": 51.52000046 },
    { "lng": 0.27277899, "lat": 51.51665878 },
    { "lng": 0.28000101, "lat": 51.52693939 },
    { "lng": 0.33611101, "lat": 51.53998947 },
    { "lng": 0.31610999, "lat": 51.56222153 },
    { "lng": 0.30833301, "lat": 51.57889175 },
    { "lng": 0.284446, "lat": 51.58388901 },
    { "lng": 0.27055699, "lat": 51.59360886 },
    { "lng": 0.251111, "lat": 51.61693954 },
    { "lng": 0.248055, "lat": 51.627491 },
    { "lng": 0.23139, "lat": 51.62916946 },
    { "lng": 0.18472201, "lat": 51.61943817 },
    { "lng": 0.112223, "lat": 51.61555099 },
    { "lng": 0.095555, "lat": 51.60277939 },
    { "lng": 0.083888, "lat": 51.60110092 },
    { "lng": 0.030832, "lat": 51.62110901 },
    { "lng": 0.02139, "lat": 51.63694 },
    { "lng": 0, "lat": 51.64580917 },
    { "lng": -0.012779, "lat": 51.64999008 },
    { "lng": -0.006944, "lat": 51.66611099 },
    { "lng": -0.011218, "lat": 51.67724991 },
    { "lng": -0.148057, "lat": 51.68915939 },
    { "lng": -0.158333, "lat": 51.67583084 },
    { "lng": -0.17333201, "lat": 51.66638184 },
    { "lng": -0.200554, "lat": 51.66222 },
    { "lng": -0.2175, "lat": 51.65415955 },
    { "lng": -0.2185795, "lat": 51.65552902 },
    { "lng": -0.25165808, "lat": 51.65075684 },
    { "lng": -0.25416699, "lat": 51.64416885 },
    { "lng": -0.32083401, "lat": 51.63444138 },
    { "lng": -0.37389001, "lat": 51.61444092 },
    { "lng": -0.43194401, "lat": 51.61526871 },
    { "lng": -0.45509729, "lat": 51.61145401 },
    { "lng": -0.49145395, "lat": 51.6305275 },
    { "lng": -0.51059043, "lat": 51.60243225 },
    { "lng": -0.49340501, "lat": 51.59098816 },
    { "lng": -0.471389, "lat": 51.54999924 },
    { "lng": -0.48444599, "lat": 51.49443817 },
    { "lng": -0.48830837, "lat": 51.48941803 },
    { "lng": -0.50117481, "lat": 51.49054718 },
    { "lng": -0.51396489, "lat": 51.47476578 },
    { "lng": -0.51626939, "lat": 51.46512222 },
    { "lng": -0.50549263, "lat": 51.46284485 },
    { "lng": -0.47808617, "lat": 51.4624939 },
    { "lng": -0.473611, "lat": 51.45888901 },
    { "lng": -0.44138801, "lat": 51.45389175 },
    { "lng": -0.44027901, "lat": 51.43804932 },
    { "lng": -0.43166599, "lat": 51.43027115 },
    { "lng": -0.40027699, "lat": 51.42499924 },
    { "lng": -0.37493101, "lat": 51.4070282 },
    { "lng": -0.34333301, "lat": 51.39416885 },
    { "lng": -0.325679, "lat": 51.39373016 },
    { "lng": -0.311667, "lat": 51.39249039 },
    { "lng": -0.30624413, "lat": 51.3837471 },
    { "lng": -0.31510291, "lat": 51.37156677 },
    { "lng": -0.31725064, "lat": 51.35446548 },
    { "lng": -0.33161607, "lat": 51.33563232 },
    { "lng": -0.31991833, "lat": 51.32309341 },
    { "lng": -0.30420882, "lat": 51.33714294 },
    { "lng": -0.2914573, "lat": 51.35313797 },
    { "lng": -0.28307828, "lat": 51.37395477 },
    { "lng": -0.25883117, "lat": 51.37169647 },
    { "lng": -0.25410262, "lat": 51.36838531 },
    { "lng": -0.243056, "lat": 51.37360001 },
    { "lng": -0.21805599, "lat": 51.35305023 },
    { "lng": -0.21944401, "lat": 51.32833099 },
    { "lng": -0.188612, "lat": 51.33972168 },
    { "lng": -0.178333, "lat": 51.33916092 },
    { "lng": -0.15111101, "lat": 51.30305099 },
    { "lng": -0.128057, "lat": 51.28916168 },
    { "lng": -0.101943, "lat": 51.29277039 },
    { "lng": -0.084722, "lat": 51.31110001 },
    { "lng": -0.065557, "lat": 51.31637955 },
    { "lng": -0.046667, "lat": 51.31555176 },
    { "lng": -0.026668, "lat": 51.33082962 },
    { "lng": 0, "lat": 51.32949829 },
    { "lng": 0.01639, "lat": 51.3185997 },
    { "lng": 0.0225, "lat": 51.28971863 },
    { "lng": 0.048334, "lat": 51.29499817 },
    { "lng": 0.054444, "lat": 51.28998947 },
    { "lng": 0.06889, "lat": 51.28248978 },
    { "lng": 0.093889, "lat": 51.28833008 },
    { "lng": 0.096665, "lat": 51.31110001 },
    { "lng": 0.119999, "lat": 51.32416916 },
    { "lng": 0.13111, "lat": 51.34111023 },
    { "lng": 0.155278, "lat": 51.35472107 },
    { "lng": 0.169167, "lat": 51.38861084 },
    { "lng": 0.16627, "lat": 51.39855576 }
  ],
  [
    { "lng": 1.37138796, "lat": 51.31183624 },
    { "lng": 1.36972201, "lat": 51.3156929 },
    { "lng": 1.36472201, "lat": 51.3156929 },
    { "lng": 1.36249995, "lat": 51.32013702 },
    { "lng": 1.37361002, "lat": 51.32791519 },
    { "lng": 1.38305497, "lat": 51.32875061 },
    { "lng": 1.39138997, "lat": 51.32597351 },
    { "lng": 1.40972102, "lat": 51.32652664 },
    { "lng": 1.415277, "lat": 51.32402802 },
    { "lng": 1.42027795, "lat": 51.32958221 },
    { "lng": 1.43250096, "lat": 51.33736038 },
    { "lng": 1.44416797, "lat": 51.35097122 },
    { "lng": 1.44583404, "lat": 51.36624908 },
    { "lng": 1.44861197, "lat": 51.36875153 },
    { "lng": 1.44972205, "lat": 51.37763977 },
    { "lng": 1.44249904, "lat": 51.38680649 },
    { "lng": 1.42416596, "lat": 51.39347076 },
    { "lng": 1.41916597, "lat": 51.39180374 },
    { "lng": 1.40805495, "lat": 51.39291763 },
    { "lng": 1.38583302, "lat": 51.39291763 },
    { "lng": 1.38083303, "lat": 51.39152908 },
    { "lng": 1.37805498, "lat": 51.38708496 },
    { "lng": 1.36472201, "lat": 51.38597107 },
    { "lng": 1.34972298, "lat": 51.38624954 },
    { "lng": 1.34194398, "lat": 51.38486099 },
    { "lng": 1.33305502, "lat": 51.38597107 },
    { "lng": 1.32694495, "lat": 51.38208389 },
    { "lng": 1.30361104, "lat": 51.38152695 },
    { "lng": 1.30083299, "lat": 51.38319397 },
    { "lng": 1.28916597, "lat": 51.38263702 },
    { "lng": 1.27749896, "lat": 51.37763977 },
    { "lng": 1.26083398, "lat": 51.3773613 },
    { "lng": 1.24527705, "lat": 51.37791824 },
    { "lng": 1.21361005, "lat": 51.38069534 },
    { "lng": 1.17750001, "lat": 51.37708282 },
    { "lng": 1.16638899, "lat": 51.37402725 },
    { "lng": 1.14027703, "lat": 51.3726387 },
    { "lng": 1.12361205, "lat": 51.37319565 },
    { "lng": 1.11972106, "lat": 51.37208176 },
    { "lng": 1.09972203, "lat": 51.3726387 },
    { "lng": 1.09361196, "lat": 51.36819458 },
    { "lng": 1.08027899, "lat": 51.36819458 },
    { "lng": 1.06639004, "lat": 51.36930466 },
    { "lng": 1.06305504, "lat": 51.36597061 },
    { "lng": 1.05749905, "lat": 51.36541748 },
    { "lng": 1.03194499, "lat": 51.36597061 },
    { "lng": 1.01472199, "lat": 51.35569382 },
    { "lng": 1.01194298, "lat": 51.35180664 },
    { "lng": 1.00583303, "lat": 51.3493042 },
    { "lng": 0.98972201, "lat": 51.34624863 },
    { "lng": 0.96694398, "lat": 51.3465271 },
    { "lng": 0.95416701, "lat": 51.34486008 },
    { "lng": 0.94138801, "lat": 51.34680557 },
    { "lng": 0.93361199, "lat": 51.34680557 },
    { "lng": 0.927499, "lat": 51.34486008 },
    { "lng": 0.91638798, "lat": 51.34541702 },
    { "lng": 0.91527802, "lat": 51.34375 },
    { "lng": 0.90083301, "lat": 51.34182358 },
    { "lng": 0.889166, "lat": 51.3465271 },
    { "lng": 0.886388, "lat": 51.34958267 },
    { "lng": 0.87694299, "lat": 51.35402679 },
    { "lng": 0.86138803, "lat": 51.35625076 },
    { "lng": 0.85250002, "lat": 51.35430527 },
    { "lng": 0.836945, "lat": 51.35374832 },
    { "lng": 0.81972301, "lat": 51.35430527 },
    { "lng": 0.81416702, "lat": 51.35874939 },
    { "lng": 0.80472201, "lat": 51.36041641 },
    { "lng": 0.78416699, "lat": 51.36069489 },
    { "lng": 0.76416701, "lat": 51.36375046 },
    { "lng": 0.76305503, "lat": 51.37125015 },
    { "lng": 0.76416701, "lat": 51.38402939 },
    { "lng": 0.75083399, "lat": 51.38819504 },
    { "lng": 0.74027699, "lat": 51.39597321 },
    { "lng": 0.735277, "lat": 51.39541626 },
    { "lng": 0.72583199, "lat": 51.39986038 },
    { "lng": 0.72250003, "lat": 51.40763855 },
    { "lng": 0.71749997, "lat": 51.4118042 },
    { "lng": 0.71972197, "lat": 51.41652679 },
    { "lng": 0.73194498, "lat": 51.41847229 },
    { "lng": 0.72805399, "lat": 51.42319489 },
    { "lng": 0.71749997, "lat": 51.42041779 },
    { "lng": 0.69638801, "lat": 51.41958237 },
    { "lng": 0.69861001, "lat": 51.41013718 },
    { "lng": 0.69583398, "lat": 51.40486145 },
    { "lng": 0.702501, "lat": 51.39513779 },
    { "lng": 0.70805502, "lat": 51.39374924 },
    { "lng": 0.71694303, "lat": 51.38819504 },
    { "lng": 0.71361101, "lat": 51.38458252 },
    { "lng": 0.70583302, "lat": 51.3829155 },
    { "lng": 0.69638801, "lat": 51.38402939 },
    { "lng": 0.702501, "lat": 51.39236069 },
    { "lng": 0.68638903, "lat": 51.39152908 },
    { "lng": 0.68250102, "lat": 51.38541794 },
    { "lng": 0.68249899, "lat": 51.38041687 },
    { "lng": 0.67416602, "lat": 51.37597275 },
    { "lng": 0.66638798, "lat": 51.37902832 },
    { "lng": 0.66750002, "lat": 51.38375092 },
    { "lng": 0.660833, "lat": 51.38708496 },
    { "lng": 0.65916699, "lat": 51.39263916 },
    { "lng": 0.649167, "lat": 51.39708328 },
    { "lng": 0.64194399, "lat": 51.39597321 },
    { "lng": 0.641388, "lat": 51.39041519 },
    { "lng": 0.63583398, "lat": 51.38819504 },
    { "lng": 0.61871314, "lat": 51.38847351 },
    { "lng": 0.61907172, "lat": 51.38735962 },
    { "lng": 0.6208595, "lat": 51.38180542 },
    { "lng": 0.62991339, "lat": 51.35365677 },
    { "lng": 0.6055187, "lat": 51.32564545 },
    { "lng": 0.53163612, "lat": 51.32905197 },
    { "lng": 0.51799393, "lat": 51.34005356 },
    { "lng": 0.44815803, "lat": 51.3654213 },
    { "lng": 0.45292687, "lat": 51.33221054 },
    { "lng": 0.40441132, "lat": 51.34779739 },
    { "lng": 0.42912629, "lat": 51.36586761 },
    { "lng": 0.46352649, "lat": 51.38949585 },
    { "lng": 0.48509443, "lat": 51.42131805 },
    { "lng": 0.45472199, "lat": 51.45279694 },
    { "lng": 0.44249901, "lat": 51.45013809 },
    { "lng": 0.44027701, "lat": 51.44763947 },
    { "lng": 0.43360999, "lat": 51.44763947 },
    { "lng": 0.41749901, "lat": 51.44430542 },
    { "lng": 0.41416699, "lat": 51.44999313 },
    { "lng": 0.38685399, "lat": 51.44845963 },
    { "lng": 0.36611199, "lat": 51.44332886 },
    { "lng": 0.34139001, "lat": 51.44638824 },
    { "lng": 0.31222099, "lat": 51.46554947 },
    { "lng": 0.26555401, "lat": 51.45666885 },
    { "lng": 0.223611, "lat": 51.47333145 },
    { "lng": 0.21139, "lat": 51.4569397 },
    { "lng": 0.18110999, "lat": 51.43777084 },
    { "lng": 0.160834, "lat": 51.41722107 },
    { "lng": 0.16627, "lat": 51.39855576 },
    { "lng": 0.169167, "lat": 51.38861084 },
    { "lng": 0.155278, "lat": 51.35472107 },
    { "lng": 0.13111, "lat": 51.34111023 },
    { "lng": 0.119999, "lat": 51.32416916 },
    { "lng": 0.096665, "lat": 51.31110001 },
    { "lng": 0.093889, "lat": 51.28833008 },
    { "lng": 0.06889, "lat": 51.28248978 },
    { "lng": 0.054444, "lat": 51.28998947 },
    { "lng": 0.055832, "lat": 51.26665878 },
    { "lng": 0.063889, "lat": 51.24222183 },
    { "lng": 0.044443, "lat": 51.20999908 },
    { "lng": 0.060279, "lat": 51.1816597 },
    { "lng": 0.056666, "lat": 51.16804886 },
    { "lng": 0.062781, "lat": 51.13587952 },
    { "lng": 0.096665, "lat": 51.13666916 },
    { "lng": 0.13249999, "lat": 51.14416885 },
    { "lng": 0.154384, "lat": 51.13933945 },
    { "lng": 0.15298761, "lat": 51.13654709 },
    { "lng": 0.18224943, "lat": 51.11698532 },
    { "lng": 0.221389, "lat": 51.12194061 },
    { "lng": 0.26694399, "lat": 51.11027908 },
    { "lng": 0.33138901, "lat": 51.11999893 },
    { "lng": 0.33527899, "lat": 51.11777115 },
    { "lng": 0.33555701, "lat": 51.10694122 },
    { "lng": 0.35916701, "lat": 51.10139084 },
    { "lng": 0.357499, "lat": 51.08639145 },
    { "lng": 0.38166699, "lat": 51.08943939 },
    { "lng": 0.40111199, "lat": 51.0819397 },
    { "lng": 0.41666701, "lat": 51.06528091 },
    { "lng": 0.474722, "lat": 51.04777908 },
    { "lng": 0.47972199, "lat": 51.03026962 },
    { "lng": 0.53694397, "lat": 51.01832962 },
    { "lng": 0.56972301, "lat": 51 },
    { "lng": 0.65805697, "lat": 51.01388931 },
    { "lng": 0.67527902, "lat": 51.00971985 },
    { "lng": 0.69583398, "lat": 50.99554825 },
    { "lng": 0.76333302, "lat": 50.99721909 },
    { "lng": 0.78666699, "lat": 50.98833084 },
    { "lng": 0.82111102, "lat": 50.94416046 },
    { "lng": 0.83722001, "lat": 50.94332886 },
    { "lng": 0.84916502, "lat": 50.95055008 },
    { "lng": 0.86666697, "lat": 50.94388962 },
    { "lng": 0.87277699, "lat": 50.93082809 },
    { "lng": 0.86771297, "lat": 50.92124939 },
    { "lng": 0.88527799, "lat": 50.91958237 },
    { "lng": 0.89083201, "lat": 50.91764069 },
    { "lng": 0.93805599, "lat": 50.9118042 },
    { "lng": 0.954723, "lat": 50.91041565 },
    { "lng": 0.973611, "lat": 50.91041565 },
    { "lng": 0.98194498, "lat": 50.91402817 },
    { "lng": 0.982499, "lat": 50.92013931 },
    { "lng": 0.97750098, "lat": 50.93013763 },
    { "lng": 0.97250098, "lat": 50.93680573 },
    { "lng": 0.97083199, "lat": 50.94458389 },
    { "lng": 0.96416599, "lat": 50.96097183 },
    { "lng": 0.96416599, "lat": 50.96847153 },
    { "lng": 0.97083199, "lat": 50.98236084 },
    { "lng": 0.97250098, "lat": 50.99013901 },
    { "lng": 0.97972298, "lat": 51.0079155 },
    { "lng": 0.995278, "lat": 51.02347183 },
    { "lng": 1.00749898, "lat": 51.03236008 },
    { "lng": 1.02805495, "lat": 51.04291534 },
    { "lng": 1.03861201, "lat": 51.04986191 },
    { "lng": 1.05527699, "lat": 51.0573616 },
    { "lng": 1.06583405, "lat": 51.06097412 },
    { "lng": 1.08583295, "lat": 51.06597137 },
    { "lng": 1.13027799, "lat": 51.07180405 },
    { "lng": 1.14527702, "lat": 51.07291794 },
    { "lng": 1.165833, "lat": 51.07291794 },
    { "lng": 1.178056, "lat": 51.07569504 },
    { "lng": 1.19138896, "lat": 51.07652664 },
    { "lng": 1.19138896, "lat": 51.08180618 },
    { "lng": 1.20139003, "lat": 51.08402634 },
    { "lng": 1.20194399, "lat": 51.08930588 },
    { "lng": 1.20694399, "lat": 51.09319305 },
    { "lng": 1.22527695, "lat": 51.0993042 },
    { "lng": 1.25138903, "lat": 51.10041809 },
    { "lng": 1.25750005, "lat": 51.10180664 },
    { "lng": 1.26916695, "lat": 51.10152817 },
    { "lng": 1.28694403, "lat": 51.10736084 },
    { "lng": 1.30194497, "lat": 51.11347198 },
    { "lng": 1.31361198, "lat": 51.11375046 },
    { "lng": 1.320279, "lat": 51.11597061 },
    { "lng": 1.31416595, "lat": 51.11902618 },
    { "lng": 1.31860995, "lat": 51.12402725 },
    { "lng": 1.32638896, "lat": 51.12513733 },
    { "lng": 1.33583403, "lat": 51.12347412 },
    { "lng": 1.34194398, "lat": 51.12569427 },
    { "lng": 1.34361005, "lat": 51.13124847 },
    { "lng": 1.35916698, "lat": 51.13402939 },
    { "lng": 1.37527895, "lat": 51.13930511 },
    { "lng": 1.38083303, "lat": 51.14236069 },
    { "lng": 1.38416696, "lat": 51.14902878 },
    { "lng": 1.39583397, "lat": 51.15597153 },
    { "lng": 1.40527701, "lat": 51.17097092 },
    { "lng": 1.40472305, "lat": 51.17986298 },
    { "lng": 1.40472305, "lat": 51.23236084 },
    { "lng": 1.39583397, "lat": 51.25458145 },
    { "lng": 1.39194405, "lat": 51.25902939 },
    { "lng": 1.38583302, "lat": 51.27319336 },
    { "lng": 1.38194501, "lat": 51.2784729 },
    { "lng": 1.37694502, "lat": 51.28874969 },
    { "lng": 1.37583196, "lat": 51.29597092 },
    { "lng": 1.37138796, "lat": 51.31183624 }
  ],
  [
    { "lng": 0.67972302, "lat": 51.39736176 },
    { "lng": 0.66805601, "lat": 51.39319611 },
    { "lng": 0.67194402, "lat": 51.39014053 },
    { "lng": 0.68305498, "lat": 51.39541626 },
    { "lng": 0.67972302, "lat": 51.39736176 }
  ],
  [
    { "lng": 0.94638902, "lat": 51.37791824 },
    { "lng": 0.945279, "lat": 51.38124847 },
    { "lng": 0.93583399, "lat": 51.39263916 },
    { "lng": 0.91027802, "lat": 51.40680695 },
    { "lng": 0.91027802, "lat": 51.40847397 },
    { "lng": 0.90194499, "lat": 51.41708374 },
    { "lng": 0.88527799, "lat": 51.42124939 },
    { "lng": 0.86805499, "lat": 51.42097092 },
    { "lng": 0.85972202, "lat": 51.42291641 },
    { "lng": 0.81916702, "lat": 51.4268074 },
    { "lng": 0.790277, "lat": 51.4398613 },
    { "lng": 0.77249998, "lat": 51.4406929 },
    { "lng": 0.76249897, "lat": 51.44208527 },
    { "lng": 0.7525, "lat": 51.44486237 },
    { "lng": 0.74472201, "lat": 51.44847107 },
    { "lng": 0.74083298, "lat": 51.43680573 },
    { "lng": 0.735277, "lat": 51.42625046 },
    { "lng": 0.74249899, "lat": 51.41236115 },
    { "lng": 0.73138899, "lat": 51.4090271 },
    { "lng": 0.72750002, "lat": 51.40569305 },
    { "lng": 0.73027903, "lat": 51.40124893 },
    { "lng": 0.74083298, "lat": 51.39875031 },
    { "lng": 0.75694501, "lat": 51.38763809 },
    { "lng": 0.76805502, "lat": 51.38347244 },
    { "lng": 0.764723, "lat": 51.37569427 },
    { "lng": 0.764723, "lat": 51.37069321 },
    { "lng": 0.77194399, "lat": 51.36791611 },
    { "lng": 0.78305697, "lat": 51.36902618 },
    { "lng": 0.78972298, "lat": 51.37319565 },
    { "lng": 0.79249901, "lat": 51.37014008 },
    { "lng": 0.79916602, "lat": 51.36847305 },
    { "lng": 0.80861002, "lat": 51.3698616 },
    { "lng": 0.82083303, "lat": 51.36902618 },
    { "lng": 0.83750099, "lat": 51.36347198 },
    { "lng": 0.86361003, "lat": 51.36264038 },
    { "lng": 0.894723, "lat": 51.35402679 },
    { "lng": 0.90805602, "lat": 51.35486221 },
    { "lng": 0.920277, "lat": 51.35791779 },
    { "lng": 0.93694401, "lat": 51.36763763 },
    { "lng": 0.94638902, "lat": 51.3670845 },
    { "lng": 0.95027697, "lat": 51.3745842 },
    { "lng": 0.94638902, "lat": 51.37791824 }
  ],
  [
    { "lng": 0.68472302, "lat": 51.41263962 },
    { "lng": 0.68138897, "lat": 51.40763855 },
    { "lng": 0.67583197, "lat": 51.40652847 },
    { "lng": 0.670834, "lat": 51.40986252 },
    { "lng": 0.66583401, "lat": 51.4081955 },
    { "lng": 0.67250001, "lat": 51.40180588 },
    { "lng": 0.67250001, "lat": 51.39847183 },
    { "lng": 0.68027699, "lat": 51.39930725 },
    { "lng": 0.691944, "lat": 51.39625168 },
    { "lng": 0.69583398, "lat": 51.39847183 },
    { "lng": 0.69138998, "lat": 51.40291595 },
    { "lng": 0.69138998, "lat": 51.4118042 },
    { "lng": 0.68472302, "lat": 51.41263962 }
  ],
  [
    { "lng": 0.67972302, "lat": 51.42375183 },
    { "lng": 0.66527802, "lat": 51.42375183 },
    { "lng": 0.67027801, "lat": 51.41402817 },
    { "lng": 0.67583197, "lat": 51.41374969 },
    { "lng": 0.67583197, "lat": 51.41847229 },
    { "lng": 0.68138897, "lat": 51.41875076 },
    { "lng": 0.68694299, "lat": 51.41458511 },
    { "lng": 0.68805498, "lat": 51.42180634 },
    { "lng": 0.67972302, "lat": 51.42375183 }
  ],
  [
    { "lng": 0.56583202, "lat": 51.4081955 },
    { "lng": 0.56083399, "lat": 51.40652847 },
    { "lng": 0.56138802, "lat": 51.40180588 },
    { "lng": 0.58249998, "lat": 51.40263748 },
    { "lng": 0.57972097, "lat": 51.40652847 },
    { "lng": 0.57305503, "lat": 51.4054184 },
    { "lng": 0.56583202, "lat": 51.4081955 }
  ],
  [
    { "lng": 0.60249901, "lat": 51.40263748 },
    { "lng": 0.59527898, "lat": 51.40041733 },
    { "lng": 0.596389, "lat": 51.39625168 },
    { "lng": 0.60416698, "lat": 51.39374924 },
    { "lng": 0.613612, "lat": 51.39764023 },
    { "lng": 0.61472201, "lat": 51.40124893 },
    { "lng": 0.60249901, "lat": 51.40263748 }
  ],
  [
    { "lng": 0.65250099, "lat": 51.44652939 },
    { "lng": 0.65472299, "lat": 51.44874954 },
    { "lng": 0.66194302, "lat": 51.4481926 },
    { "lng": 0.66305602, "lat": 51.44374847 },
    { "lng": 0.66972202, "lat": 51.44291687 },
    { "lng": 0.67472303, "lat": 51.4323616 },
    { "lng": 0.70361102, "lat": 51.43319321 },
    { "lng": 0.71527702, "lat": 51.43597412 },
    { "lng": 0.72361201, "lat": 51.44319534 },
    { "lng": 0.72305602, "lat": 51.45458221 },
    { "lng": 0.71861202, "lat": 51.46125031 },
    { "lng": 0.70083201, "lat": 51.47263718 },
    { "lng": 0.694722, "lat": 51.47236252 },
    { "lng": 0.68694299, "lat": 51.4743042 },
    { "lng": 0.66250002, "lat": 51.47541809 },
    { "lng": 0.660833, "lat": 51.47763824 },
    { "lng": 0.64805698, "lat": 51.47680664 },
    { "lng": 0.641388, "lat": 51.47874832 },
    { "lng": 0.62583297, "lat": 51.47735977 },
    { "lng": 0.61416602, "lat": 51.47513962 },
    { "lng": 0.61194402, "lat": 51.47874832 },
    { "lng": 0.58583403, "lat": 51.48430634 },
    { "lng": 0.57972097, "lat": 51.48041534 },
    { "lng": 0.57527697, "lat": 51.48430634 },
    { "lng": 0.55916601, "lat": 51.48458481 },
    { "lng": 0.54805499, "lat": 51.48736191 },
    { "lng": 0.52527702, "lat": 51.48430634 },
    { "lng": 0.51583302, "lat": 51.48569489 },
    { "lng": 0.49916801, "lat": 51.48597336 },
    { "lng": 0.481388, "lat": 51.48736191 },
    { "lng": 0.46805501, "lat": 51.48263931 },
    { "lng": 0.46694499, "lat": 51.47930527 },
    { "lng": 0.46138901, "lat": 51.47513962 },
    { "lng": 0.458056, "lat": 51.46652603 },
    { "lng": 0.454166, "lat": 51.46541595 },
    { "lng": 0.45750001, "lat": 51.45986176 },
    { "lng": 0.458056, "lat": 51.45402908 },
    { "lng": 0.45472199, "lat": 51.45279694 },
    { "lng": 0.48509443, "lat": 51.42131805 },
    { "lng": 0.46352649, "lat": 51.38949585 },
    { "lng": 0.42912629, "lat": 51.36586761 },
    { "lng": 0.40441132, "lat": 51.34779739 },
    { "lng": 0.45292687, "lat": 51.33221054 },
    { "lng": 0.44815803, "lat": 51.3654213 },
    { "lng": 0.51799393, "lat": 51.34005356 },
    { "lng": 0.53163612, "lat": 51.32905197 },
    { "lng": 0.6055187, "lat": 51.32564545 },
    { "lng": 0.62991339, "lat": 51.35365677 },
    { "lng": 0.6208595, "lat": 51.38180542 },
    { "lng": 0.61638802, "lat": 51.37874985 },
    { "lng": 0.605277, "lat": 51.38152695 },
    { "lng": 0.60805601, "lat": 51.38597107 },
    { "lng": 0.59805501, "lat": 51.38986206 },
    { "lng": 0.57694501, "lat": 51.39097214 },
    { "lng": 0.555278, "lat": 51.39875031 },
    { "lng": 0.55027699, "lat": 51.40652847 },
    { "lng": 0.54027897, "lat": 51.41013718 },
    { "lng": 0.554721, "lat": 51.41236115 },
    { "lng": 0.558056, "lat": 51.40958405 },
    { "lng": 0.57305503, "lat": 51.41298294 },
    { "lng": 0.57694501, "lat": 51.41569519 },
    { "lng": 0.59694499, "lat": 51.41624832 },
    { "lng": 0.60416698, "lat": 51.41458511 },
    { "lng": 0.62472302, "lat": 51.42402649 },
    { "lng": 0.62583297, "lat": 51.4268074 },
    { "lng": 0.61861002, "lat": 51.42902756 },
    { "lng": 0.62527901, "lat": 51.43541718 },
    { "lng": 0.63472098, "lat": 51.43930435 },
    { "lng": 0.64972299, "lat": 51.43486023 },
    { "lng": 0.65305501, "lat": 51.4370842 },
    { "lng": 0.660833, "lat": 51.4370842 },
    { "lng": 0.65749902, "lat": 51.4426384 },
    { "lng": 0.65250099, "lat": 51.44652939 }
  ]
]
```

---

Comment: pass it by context ?

Comment: @xadm specifically need to query it with graphQL

Comment: why? what is the difference? ... gatsby context, not react

Comment: @xadm are you talking about gatsby-browser?

Comment: gatsby-node.js ... https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/reference/config-files/gatsby-node/#introduction

Comment: @Xadm how would you suggest I use gatsby-node.js to pass this?

Comment: https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/how-to/sourcing-data/sourcing-from-json-or-yaml/ https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/creating-and-modifying-pages/